# highcharts missing module for geo heatmap angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am totally new to HightChart. I have one requirement where I have to create a geo-heatmap using HightCharts in Angular. After doing some Google searches, I was able to create a chart, but I am getting an error. Check the [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1R42.png). Following is my function where I am initializing the geo-heatmap chart.

```
initHeatMap(topology: any, Highcharts: any, div: string,): void {
        let minColor: any;
        let maxColor: any
        let minValue = 1;
        let maxValue = 10;
        if (Highcharts?.getOptions()?.colors) {
            minColor = Highcharts.getOptions().colors?.[0] || '#615E9B';
        }
        if (Highcharts?.getOptions()?.colors) {
            maxColor = Highcharts.getOptions().colors?.[1] || '#00e272';
        }
        Highcharts.mapChart(div, {
            chart: {
                map: topology,
                type:'geoheatmap'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Geo Heatmap',
                align: 'left'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'HighChart Geo Heatmap',
                align: 'left'
            },

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                },
                enableButtons: true,
                enableMouseWheelZoom: true
            },
            // xAxis: {
            //  type: 'linear'
            // },
            // yAxis: {
            //  type: 'linear'
            // },
            colorAxis: {
                min: 0,
                stops: [
                    [0, '#00ff00'], // Low intensity color
                    [0.5, '#ffff00'], // Medium intensity color
                    [1, '#ff0000'] // High intensity color
                ]
            },
            series: [{

                name: 'Heatmap',
                keys: ['hc-key', 'value'],
                joinBy: 'hc-key',
                data: this.getData(),
                // mapData: Highcharts.maps[this.customMap],
                mapData: topology,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        color: minColor
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{points.name}: {point.value}'
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                },
                // type: 'geoheatmap'
            }]
        });
    }
```

Package Json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~15.2.9",
"@angular/cdk": "^14.1.2",
"@angular/common": "~15.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "~15.2.9",
"@angular/core": "~15.2.9",
"@angular/forms": "~15.2.9",
"@angular/localize": "~15.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~15.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.2.9",
"@angular/router": "~15.2.9",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.2.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
"alertifyjs": "^1.13.1",
"angular-datatables": "^15.0.1",
"angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.12",
"angular-plotly.js": "^4.0.4",
"bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
"core-js": "^3.25.5",
"datatables-fixedcolumns": "^3.1.0",
"datatables.net": "^1.12.1",
"datatables.net-dt": "^1.12.1",
"datatables.net-select": "^1.4.0",
"datatables.net-select-dt": "^1.4.0",
"echarts": "^5.4.2",
"highcharts": "^11.1.0",
"highcharts-angular": "^3.1.2",
"highcharts-custom-events": "^3.0.10",
"@highcharts/map-collection": "^2.0.1",
"jspdf": "^2.5.1",
"jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
"leaflet": "^1.9.4",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
"ng-http-loader": "^12.0.0",
"ng-sidebar": "^9.4.2",
"ngx-chips": "^3.0.0",
"ngx-dropzone": "^3.1.0",
"ngx-echarts": "^14.0.0",
"ngx-summernote": "^0.8.9",
"plotly.js-dist-min": "^2.14.0",
"primeicons": "^5.0.0",
"primeng": "^15.4.1",
"rxjs": "~7.5.6",
"summernote": "^0.8.20",
"uuid": "^9.0.1",
"xlsx": "^0.18.5",
"yarn": "^1.22.19",
"zone.js": "^0.11.8"
```

}

I'd be happy if you provide any help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After conducting some research and consulting Google, I've found a solution to my question, which may also benefit others. Instead of utilizing the HighCharts library, I'm opting for Google Visualization
[Heatmap Layer][1]
[Heatmap Using javascript][2]

The Heatmap Layer is part of the google.maps.visualization library, and is not loaded by default. The Visualization classes are a self-contained library, separate from the main Maps JavaScript API code. To use the functionality contained within this library, you must first load it using the libraries parameter in the Maps JavaScript API bootstrap URL:

```
<script async 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
```

And that's all. I am able to create an heatmap using Geo JSON in Google Map
[1]: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap
[2]: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Highcharts in Angular, it is best to use the official wrapper: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

There is a section in README.md that explains how to use the modules: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module

In short, you should import a given module and initialize it:

```js
import Geoheatmap from 'highcharts/modules/geoheatmap';

Geoheatmap(Highcharts);
```

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-map-geoheatmap-angular

Comment: Thanks @michał for the quick reply but when i try to import the Geoheatmap i am getting error 
Could not find a declaration file for module 'highcharts/modules/geoheatmap'. 'd:/App/GeoApp/node_modules/highcharts/modules/geoheatmap.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  If the 'highcharts' package actually exposes this module, try adding a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'highcharts/modules/geoheatmap';`

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Highcharts?

Comment: I am using 11.1.0